# Query to return rows of Nested XML nodes

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I am trying to return data of node "attachDocument" of XML script below. Script below to return 7 rows (7 nodes of “atttachDocument” under consignment node) but should be 8 (one under root node “declaration” label as **Struggling to include **) that I am struggling to return it thru Query... Can someone help query to return all 8 rows of node "attachDocument"?

Thanks in Advance.

XML...

```xml
DECLARE @sqlxml XML =
N'<declaration xmlns="http://xyz.IND/NCCS/v2">
  <identification>43006267</identification>
  <type>ICR</type>
  <functionalReference>D2710ICRAT0001</functionalReference>
  <transactionType>9</transactionType>
  <submitter>
    <identifier>40063605C</identifier>
  </submitter>
  <additionalDocument>
    <type>OTH</type>
    <identifier>213</identifier>
  </additionalDocument>
  <additionalInformationMAC>
    <accountNumber>123123</accountNumber>
    <accountName>Sample MPI Ac Name</accountName>
  </additionalInformationMAC>
  <carrier>
    <identifier>40063605C</identifier>
  </carrier>
  <consignment>
    <sequence>1</sequence>
    <additionalInformationHAN>
      <text>HANDLING INSTRUCTIONS</text>
    </additionalInformationHAN>
    <additionalInformationITR>
      <departureDate>20170414</departureDate>
      <craftName>A.P. MOLLER</craftName>
      <transportMode>1</transportMode>
      <voyageNumber>123123</voyageNumber>
    </additionalInformationITR>
    <additionalInformationMAC>
      <accountNumber>1233445</accountNumber>
      <accountName>Test MPI Account Name</accountName>
    </additionalInformationMAC>
    <additionalInformationOSP>
      <code>N</code>
    </additionalInformationOSP>
    <additionalInformationOSR>
      <text>148952973</text>
    </additionalInformationOSR>
    <associatedTransportDocument>
      <identifier>YH4094034</identifier>
      <type>MB</type>
    </associatedTransportDocument>
    <consignee>
      <name>CONSIGNEE</name>
      <address>
        <city>a fluffy chicken.</city>
        <countryCode>IND</countryCode>
        <state>That is all.</state>
        <line>Once upon a time there was</line>
        <postcode>Sorry.</postcode>
      </address>
    </consignee>
    <consignmentItem>
      <sequence>1</sequence>
      <additionalInformationMAS>
        <approvedSystemNumber>323232</approvedSystemNumber>
      </additionalInformationMAS>
      <commodity>
        <cargoDescription>Cargo.</cargoDescription>
        <identifier>45612389</identifier>
        <commodityIdentifierType>MC</commodityIdentifierType>
        <temperature>
          <flashpoint>
            <quantity>250</quantity>
          </flashpoint>
          <storageRequirement>
            <quantity>10</quantity>
          </storageRequirement>
          <minimumStorageRequirement>
            <quantity>-1</quantity>
          </minimumStorageRequirement>
          <maximumStorageRequirement>
            <quantity>52</quantity>
          </maximumStorageRequirement>
        </temperature>
      </commodity>
      <goodsMeasure>
        <grossWeight>
          <quantity>10</quantity>
          <unitOfMeasurement>KGM</unitOfMeasurement>
        </grossWeight>
      </goodsMeasure>
      <packaging>
        <sequence>1</sequence>
        <quantity>10</quantity>
        <type>PF</type>
      </packaging>
      <transportEquipment>
        <identifier>CQDE1928327</identifier>
      </transportEquipment>
    </consignmentItem>
    <consignor>
      <name>CONSIGNOR</name>
      <address>
        <city>fields carefully</city>
        <countryCode>AF</countryCode>
        <state>you could write</state>
        <line>If you use these</line>
        <postcode>a story</postcode>
      </address>
    </consignor>
    <deliveryDestination>
      <identifier>25002</identifier>
      <name>CONSIGNEE</name>
      <address>
        <city>a fluffy chicken.</city>
        <countryCode>IND</countryCode>
        <state>That is all.</state>
        <line>Once upon a time there was</line>
        <postcode>Sorry.</postcode>
      </address>
    </deliveryDestination>
    <freightPaymentMethod>AB</freightPaymentMethod>
    <goodsConsignedPlace>AEAJM</goodsConsignedPlace>
    <goodsLocation>
      <identifier>19258K</identifier>
    </goodsLocation>
    <loadingLocation>AUABP</loadingLocation>
    <deliveryNotificationParty>
      <name>Yetta Nuther</name>
      <communication>
        <value>yettanuther3377@example.invalid</value>
        <type>EM</type>
      </communication>
    </deliveryNotificationParty>
    <stuffingEstablishment>
      <name>Pack Location Name</name>
      <address>
        <city>City</city>
        <countryCode>IND</countryCode>
        <state>My</state>
        <line>Street</line>
        <postcode>000</postcode>
      </address>
    </stuffingEstablishment>
    <bill>
      <identifier>UJ940344</identifier>
      <type>BM</type>
    </bill>
    <transportEquipment>
      <sequence>1</sequence>
      <additionalInformationMAS>
        <approvedSystemNumber>43434343</approvedSystemNumber>
      </additionalInformationMAS>
      <characteristicsCode>12</characteristicsCode>
      <fullness>5</fullness>
      <identifier>CQDE1928327</identifier>
      <seal>
        <sequence>1</sequence>
        <identifier>UJ43433434</identifier>
      </seal>
      <stowPosition>BBBRRTTT</stowPosition>
      <containerPackLocation>
        <name>Pack Location Name</name>
      </containerPackLocation>
    </transportEquipment>
    <transitDestination>
      <identifier>25066</identifier>
    </transitDestination>
    <attachDocument>
      <category>CQD</category>
      <mimeCode>image/jpeg</mimeCode>
      <URI>efda0520-2e4e-4916-a89a-615e52671e01-location</URI>
      <filename>0.jpg</filename>
      <sequence>1</sequence>
      <contentSize>35581</contentSize>
    </attachDocument>
    <attachDocument>
      <category>INV</category>
      <mimeCode>image/jpeg</mimeCode>
      <URI>4d0a0102-291c-438a-abe6-679bcfc300c6-location</URI>
      <filename>0.jpg</filename>
      <sequence>2</sequence>
      <contentSize>35581</contentSize>
    </attachDocument>
    <attachDocument>
      <category>PER</category>
      <mimeCode>image/jpeg</mimeCode>
      <URI>2f6dcc50-a9d2-4d70-8688-89d7ce636bd4-location</URI>
      <filename>0.jpg</filename>
      <sequence>3</sequence>
      <contentSize>35581</contentSize>
    </attachDocument>
    <attachDocument>
      <category>OTH</category>
      <mimeCode>image/jpeg</mimeCode>
      <URI>850766a2-3c09-42fc-ad6a-20de89a3b255-location</URI>
      <filename>0.jpg</filename>
      <sequence>4</sequence>
      <contentSize>35581</contentSize>
    </attachDocument>
    <attachDocument>
      <category>PAC</category>
      <mimeCode>image/jpeg</mimeCode>
      <URI>1468c726-dbf2-4532-9252-b027e9fc523f-location</URI>
      <filename>0.jpg</filename>
      <sequence>5</sequence>
      <contentSize>35581</contentSize>
    </attachDocument>
    <attachDocument>
      <category>BOL</category>
      <mimeCode>image/jpeg</mimeCode>
      <URI>7942b5a3-93ba-493f-b2b3-cf504b179a17-location</URI>
      <filename>0.jpg</filename>
      <sequence>6</sequence>
      <contentSize>35581</contentSize>
    </attachDocument>
    <attachDocument>
      <category>CER</category>
      <mimeCode>image/jpeg</mimeCode>
      <URI>a2f23eb0-9dab-4851-9929-31b4273f26d5-location</URI>
      <filename>0.jpg</filename>
      <sequence>7</sequence>
      <contentSize>35581</contentSize>
    </attachDocument>
  </consignment>
  <remarks>
    <text>Ghost in the shell.</text>
  </remarks>
  <attachDocument>    **Struggling to include ***
    <category>OTH</category>
    <mimeCode>image/jpeg</mimeCode>
    <URI>4d4f5d5b-cbe7-4751-8817-27b05e58ce9e-location</URI>
    <filename>0.jpg</filename>
    <sequence>1</sequence>
    <contentSize>35581</contentSize>
  </attachDocument>
  <TSWExtension>
    <MIGVersion>V1.0</MIGVersion>
  </TSWExtension>
</declaration>'
```

Query...

```sql
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://xyz.IND/NCCS/v2')
SELECT
response.value('(category/text())[1]','varchar(50)') as Category,
response.value('(mimeCode/text())[1]','varchar(50)') as MimeCode,
response.value('(URI/text())[1]','varchar(50)') as URI,
response.value('(filename/text())[1]','varchar(50)') as [FileName],
response.value('(contentSize/text())[1]','varchar(50)') as ContentSize,
response.value('(sequence/text())[1]','varchar(100)') as Sequence
FROM @sqlxml.nodes('/declaration/consignment/attachDocument') AS T(response);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the  following solution.

It will find the `<attachDocument>` element anywhere under the root of the XML.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml XML =
N'<declaration xmlns="http://xyz.IND/NCCS/v2">
    <identification>43006267</identification>
    <type>ICR</type>
    <functionalReference>D2710ICRAT0001</functionalReference>
    <transactionType>9</transactionType>
    <submitter>
        <identifier>40063605C</identifier>
    </submitter>
    <additionalDocument>
        <type>OTH</type>
        <identifier>213</identifier>
    </additionalDocument>
    <additionalInformationMAC>
        <accountNumber>123123</accountNumber>
        <accountName>Sample MPI Ac Name</accountName>
    </additionalInformationMAC>
    <carrier>
        <identifier>40063605C</identifier>
    </carrier>
    <consignment>
        <sequence>1</sequence>
        <additionalInformationHAN>
            <text>HANDLING INSTRUCTIONS</text>
        </additionalInformationHAN>
        <additionalInformationITR>
            <departureDate>20170414</departureDate>
            <craftName>A.P. MOLLER</craftName>
            <transportMode>1</transportMode>
            <voyageNumber>123123</voyageNumber>
        </additionalInformationITR>
        <additionalInformationMAC>
            <accountNumber>1233445</accountNumber>
            <accountName>Test MPI Account Name</accountName>
        </additionalInformationMAC>
        <additionalInformationOSP>
            <code>N</code>
        </additionalInformationOSP>
        <additionalInformationOSR>
            <text>148952973</text>
        </additionalInformationOSR>
        <associatedTransportDocument>
            <identifier>YH4094034</identifier>
            <type>MB</type>
        </associatedTransportDocument>
        <consignee>
            <name>CONSIGNEE</name>
            <address>
                <city>a fluffy chicken.</city>
                <countryCode>IND</countryCode>
                <state>That is all.</state>
                <line>Once upon a time there was</line>
                <postcode>Sorry.</postcode>
            </address>
        </consignee>
        <consignmentItem>
            <sequence>1</sequence>
            <additionalInformationMAS>
                <approvedSystemNumber>323232</approvedSystemNumber>
            </additionalInformationMAS>
            <commodity>
                <cargoDescription>Cargo.</cargoDescription>
                <identifier>45612389</identifier>
                <commodityIdentifierType>MC</commodityIdentifierType>
                <temperature>
                    <flashpoint>
                        <quantity>250</quantity>
                    </flashpoint>
                    <storageRequirement>
                        <quantity>10</quantity>
                    </storageRequirement>
                    <minimumStorageRequirement>
                        <quantity>-1</quantity>
                    </minimumStorageRequirement>
                    <maximumStorageRequirement>
                        <quantity>52</quantity>
                    </maximumStorageRequirement>
                </temperature>
            </commodity>
            <goodsMeasure>
                <grossWeight>
                    <quantity>10</quantity>
                    <unitOfMeasurement>KGM</unitOfMeasurement>
                </grossWeight>
            </goodsMeasure>
            <packaging>
                <sequence>1</sequence>
                <quantity>10</quantity>
                <type>PF</type>
            </packaging>
            <transportEquipment>
                <identifier>CQDE1928327</identifier>
            </transportEquipment>
        </consignmentItem>
        <consignor>
            <name>CONSIGNOR</name>
            <address>
                <city>fields carefully</city>
                <countryCode>AF</countryCode>
                <state>you could write</state>
                <line>If you use these</line>
                <postcode>a story</postcode>
            </address>
        </consignor>
        <deliveryDestination>
            <identifier>25002</identifier>
            <name>CONSIGNEE</name>
            <address>
                <city>a fluffy chicken.</city>
                <countryCode>IND</countryCode>
                <state>That is all.</state>
                <line>Once upon a time there was</line>
                <postcode>Sorry.</postcode>
            </address>
        </deliveryDestination>
        <freightPaymentMethod>AB</freightPaymentMethod>
        <goodsConsignedPlace>AEAJM</goodsConsignedPlace>
        <goodsLocation>
            <identifier>19258K</identifier>
        </goodsLocation>
        <loadingLocation>AUABP</loadingLocation>
        <deliveryNotificationParty>
            <name>Yetta Nuther</name>
            <communication>
                <value>yettanuther3377@example.invalid</value>
                <type>EM</type>
            </communication>
        </deliveryNotificationParty>
        <stuffingEstablishment>
            <name>Pack Location Name</name>
            <address>
                <city>City</city>
                <countryCode>IND</countryCode>
                <state>My</state>
                <line>Street</line>
                <postcode>000</postcode>
            </address>
        </stuffingEstablishment>
        <bill>
            <identifier>UJ940344</identifier>
            <type>BM</type>
        </bill>
        <transportEquipment>
            <sequence>1</sequence>
            <additionalInformationMAS>
                <approvedSystemNumber>43434343</approvedSystemNumber>
            </additionalInformationMAS>
            <characteristicsCode>12</characteristicsCode>
            <fullness>5</fullness>
            <identifier>CQDE1928327</identifier>
            <seal>
                <sequence>1</sequence>
                <identifier>UJ43433434</identifier>
            </seal>
            <stowPosition>BBBRRTTT</stowPosition>
            <containerPackLocation>
                <name>Pack Location Name</name>
            </containerPackLocation>
        </transportEquipment>
        <transitDestination>
            <identifier>25066</identifier>
        </transitDestination>
        <attachDocument>
            <category>CQD</category>
            <mimeCode>image/jpeg</mimeCode>
            <URI>efda0520-2e4e-4916-a89a-615e52671e01-location</URI>
            <filename>0.jpg</filename>
            <sequence>1</sequence>
            <contentSize>35581</contentSize>
        </attachDocument>
        <attachDocument>
            <category>INV</category>
            <mimeCode>image/jpeg</mimeCode>
            <URI>4d0a0102-291c-438a-abe6-679bcfc300c6-location</URI>
            <filename>0.jpg</filename>
            <sequence>2</sequence>
            <contentSize>35581</contentSize>
        </attachDocument>
        <attachDocument>
            <category>PER</category>
            <mimeCode>image/jpeg</mimeCode>
            <URI>2f6dcc50-a9d2-4d70-8688-89d7ce636bd4-location</URI>
            <filename>0.jpg</filename>
            <sequence>3</sequence>
            <contentSize>35581</contentSize>
        </attachDocument>
        <attachDocument>
            <category>OTH</category>
            <mimeCode>image/jpeg</mimeCode>
            <URI>850766a2-3c09-42fc-ad6a-20de89a3b255-location</URI>
            <filename>0.jpg</filename>
            <sequence>4</sequence>
            <contentSize>35581</contentSize>
        </attachDocument>
        <attachDocument>
            <category>PAC</category>
            <mimeCode>image/jpeg</mimeCode>
            <URI>1468c726-dbf2-4532-9252-b027e9fc523f-location</URI>
            <filename>0.jpg</filename>
            <sequence>5</sequence>
            <contentSize>35581</contentSize>
        </attachDocument>
        <attachDocument>
            <category>BOL</category>
            <mimeCode>image/jpeg</mimeCode>
            <URI>7942b5a3-93ba-493f-b2b3-cf504b179a17-location</URI>
            <filename>0.jpg</filename>
            <sequence>6</sequence>
            <contentSize>35581</contentSize>
        </attachDocument>
        <attachDocument>
            <category>CER</category>
            <mimeCode>image/jpeg</mimeCode>
            <URI>a2f23eb0-9dab-4851-9929-31b4273f26d5-location</URI>
            <filename>0.jpg</filename>
            <sequence>7</sequence>
            <contentSize>35581</contentSize>
        </attachDocument>
    </consignment>
    <remarks>
        <text>Ghost in the shell.</text>
    </remarks>
    <attachDocument>**Struggling to include ***
        <category>OTH</category>
        <mimeCode>image/jpeg</mimeCode>
        <URI>4d4f5d5b-cbe7-4751-8817-27b05e58ce9e-location</URI>
        <filename>0.jpg</filename>
        <sequence>1</sequence>
        <contentSize>35581</contentSize>
    </attachDocument>
    <TSWExtension>
        <MIGVersion>V1.0</MIGVersion>
    </TSWExtension>
</declaration>';

WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://xyz.IND/NCCS/v2')
SELECT c.value('(category/text())[1]','varchar(50)') as Category
    , c.value('(mimeCode/text())[1]','varchar(50)') as MimeCode
    , c.value('(URI/text())[1]','varchar(50)') as URI
    , c.value('(filename/text())[1]','varchar(50)') as [FileName]
    , c.value('(contentSize/text())[1]','varchar(50)') as ContentSize
    , c.value('(sequence/text())[1]','varchar(100)') as [Sequence]
from @xml.nodes ('/declaration//attachDocument') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----------+------------+-----------------------------------------------+----------+-------------+----------+
| Category |  MimeCode  |                      URI                      | FileName | ContentSize | Sequence |
+----------+------------+-----------------------------------------------+----------+-------------+----------+
| CQD      | image/jpeg | efda0520-2e4e-4916-a89a-615e52671e01-location | 0.jpg    |       35581 |        1 |
| INV      | image/jpeg | 4d0a0102-291c-438a-abe6-679bcfc300c6-location | 0.jpg    |       35581 |        2 |
| PER      | image/jpeg | 2f6dcc50-a9d2-4d70-8688-89d7ce636bd4-location | 0.jpg    |       35581 |        3 |
| OTH      | image/jpeg | 850766a2-3c09-42fc-ad6a-20de89a3b255-location | 0.jpg    |       35581 |        4 |
| PAC      | image/jpeg | 1468c726-dbf2-4532-9252-b027e9fc523f-location | 0.jpg    |       35581 |        5 |
| BOL      | image/jpeg | 7942b5a3-93ba-493f-b2b3-cf504b179a17-location | 0.jpg    |       35581 |        6 |
| CER      | image/jpeg | a2f23eb0-9dab-4851-9929-31b4273f26d5-location | 0.jpg    |       35581 |        7 |
| OTH      | image/jpeg | 4d4f5d5b-cbe7-4751-8817-27b05e58ce9e-location | 0.jpg    |       35581 |        1 |
+----------+------------+-----------------------------------------------+----------+-------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Query branches, apply nodes()

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://xyz.IND/NCCS/v2')
select 
   response.value('(category/text())[1]','varchar(50)') as Category,
   response.value('(mimeCode/text())[1]','varchar(50)') as MimeCode,
   response.value('(URI/text())[1]','varchar(50)') as URI,
   response.value('(filename/text())[1]','varchar(50)') as [FileName],
   response.value('(contentSize/text())[1]','varchar(50)') as ContentSize,
   response.value('(sequence/text())[1]','varchar(100)') as Sequence
   from @x.nodes ('/declaration') n1(n)
   cross apply (
     select n1.n.query('attachDocument') xml1
     union all
     select n1.n.query('consignment/attachDocument') 
   ) t
   cross apply t.xml1.nodes('attachDocument') t2(response)
```

Comment: Dealing with other situation... need to return node ` <consignor>
            <name>CONSIGNOR</name>
            <address>
                <city>fields carefully</city>
                <countryCode>AF</countryCode>
                <state>you could write</state>
                <line>If you use these</line>
                <postcode>a story</postcode>
            </address>
        </consignor`
Tried to make query dynamic to pick up any hierarchy node(s) if require but returning NULL values. 
Can someone help to create dynamic Query?

Thanks in advance.